# Rogers-Ramanujan identity as a modular form

Tags: modular-forms, hypergeometric-function, q-series

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogers%E2%80%93Ramanujan_identities) on the Rogers-Ramanujan identities remarks that $$q^{-1/60} G(q) = q^{-1/60} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{q^{n^2}}{(1-q)...(1-q^n)} = q^{-1/60} \prod_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1 - q^{5n+1})(1 - q^{5n+4})}$$ is a modular function; that is, a meromorphic modular form of weight zero whose only possible poles are at cusps. This is also discussed on mathoverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29117/what-is-the-relationship-between-modular-forms-and-the-rogers-ramanujan-identiti).

Taken at face value this cannot be true because it implies that $(q^{-1/60} G(q))^{-1}$ is a holomorphic modular form of weight $0$ and therefore constant (right?) **Edit:** this logic is flawed; $q^{-1/60} G(q)$ can have zeros at cusps other than $\infty$.

I would like to know in a little more detail how to interpret this as an identity of modular forms.

Comment: Who said $f(z) = q^{1/60} \prod_{n=0}^\infty (1-q^{5n+1})(1-q^{5n+4})$ with $q = e^{2i \pi 60 z}$ was weight $0$ modular ?. Also even if it was weight $0$ modular, you have no clue if it is holomorphic at every cusps.

Comment: @reuns Yes, you're right, thanks. Re weight $0$: this is implied in "modular function", and seems reasonable anyway since the product of both identities, $q^{1/60} \prod_{n=0}^{\infty} (1 - q^{5n+1})(1-q^{5n+4}) \cdot q^{-11/60} \prod_{n=0}^{\infty} (1 - q^{5n+2})(1 - q^{5n+3})$, is $\frac{\eta(\tau)}{\eta(5\tau)}$ and has weight $0$.

Comment: Looking at things like $\prod_{k=1}^5 \eta(q e^{2i \pi k/5})^{\hat{a}(k)}$ with $\hat{a}(k)$ the discrete Fourier transform of a $5$-periodic sequence, it could be half the coefficient of $(1-q^5)$ which tells us the weight of modularity.